# Show a shipping rate based on zip, province and country in shopify

Tags: ruby, shopify

I would like to show a shipping rate if zip code matches a number of zip codes, and county is GB and hide that shipping rate otherwise. Shopify has a sample but

- it accepts singe zip code
- it need province, this is not applicable in uk
- it hides rates that are not given in list. I would like to display them.
  sample is available here.

https://help.shopify.com/en/manual/checkout-settings/script-editor/examples/shipping-scripts#show-rates-for-a-specific-zip-code-province-and-country

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: The above script is for Shopify plus, do you want to add it to Shopify plus store?

Comment: yes, I have shopify plus

Answer (score 1):

If you are not on Plus, your best bet is to register a CarrierService. Shopify will send all checkouts to that service. In your service, you audit the payload. Depending on the contents, like country, zip etc, you can either return a rate or not. This solves your problem.

Comment: I do have shopify plus

Comment: You can always contact me as an Expert. I can easily fix your Plus scripts to work as you wish. I have done that for many many businesses.